# how to allow special characters in schema validation of XML

Tags: xml-validation

I have xml with a tag name  that contains '&' like  D&G .
This xml is being validated against a XSD that has  element definition for nm as below

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="nm" type="Max70Text"/>


<xs:simpleType name="Max70Text">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="70"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

in the code 
....

```
InputStream is  = new FileInputStream(l_file);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");
Source source = new StreamSource(isr);
schemaValidator.validate(source);
```

...
i get SAX Error after the validate method is executed. How  can i avoid this exception and make ampersand skip the validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have xml with a tag name that contains '&' " - no you don't. You have some text that looks kind of like XML at first glance but isn't really XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.1" (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Name) '&' character is not a valid character for the element name.